# Playing audio from array - Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop, unity-game-engine

Im currently getting this error "Cannot implicitly convert Type JsonData.Message[] to Unity engine.audioclip": on this line of code:

```
source.clip = content.queryResult.fulfillmentMessages;
```

JsonData.Message :

```
[Serializable]
public class Message
{

    public SimpleResponses simpleResponses;

}
```

Other Classes

```
[Serializable]
public class SimpleResponses{
    public SimpleResponse[] simpleResponses;
}

[Serializable]
public class SimpleResponse{
    public string text_to_speech;
    public string ssml;
    public string displayText;

}
```

What is the best way to play the data that's stored in the array?

Answer (score 0):

i suppose its an array od audio so try for example :

```
source.clip = content.queryResult.fulfillmentMessages[0] as UnityEngine.AudioClip;
```

to be sure `content.queryResult.fulfillmentMessages.Length > 0`

Comment: `source.clip = content.queryResult.fulfillmentMessages[0] as UnityEngine.AudioClip;` This gives me an error, Cannot convert type JsonData.Message to UnityEngine.AudioClip. via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion

Comment: yes thanks,  fix the bad paste dunno if that fix your problem, i cant test. i cant know if Jsm.Message[] has the same format than Unityaudio clip

Comment: so its not the same format, you have to do a conversion of format..